# Young adult fantasy book series about the 13th child of a blacksmith

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult, magic

I read these books a couple of decades ago. Not sure when they were published, but I thought they were recent then. I got through three books, but am not sure how many more there were.

In the story, a blacksmith first helps then marries a woman. They have 12 beautiful children and she warns him that the 13th will be different. The 13th child (a son) is born ugly... like the mother.
The mother disappears.
The child grows up and his siblings love and help raise him.
He goes exploring, finds gold and brings it home. The blacksmith tries to use it for tools for people. A pair of scissors, but they're too soft.
People get angry. The 13th child takes the gold and throws it away.
It turns out that he can work magic.

In another book, he finds his mother. She can work magic too. He starts to learn. One training method requires him to hold image of an apple in his mind; if he fails he is "shocked".

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year/s did you read these books and when do you think they might've been published? Also, roughly how many books were in the series?

Comment: They were read a couple decades ago. Not sure of publication, but I though they were recent then.
I got through 3 books, not sure how many more there were.

Comment: The Tales of Alvin Maker had a seventh son (the thirteenth child in total). He was the son of a miller, although he was *apprenticed* to a blacksmith https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Literature/TheTalesOfAlvinMaker

Comment: And Alvin did turn an anvil into gold in the third book. It doesn't really fit though. You'd have thought a novel about the (ugly) 13th child of a blacksmith would be easy to Google, but apparently not.

Comment: @JohnRennie - I'm wondering if they're conflating two different books

Comment: The stuff I put down covered several books of the series. I'll look at Alvin Maker and see if anything goes *ding ding ding*.
Here's hoping!

Comment: Nope. Not Alvin Maker. Seemed SO close. Ah well...onward!